# Save the state of array after custom filter in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-filter

I have two arrays of data which is being shown in a tree form and a relation between them.

```
$scope.types=['odd','prime','square','even'];
$scope.items=['1','4','3','8'];
```

> div ng-repeat="item in items| customFilter">item

And

> div ng-repeat="type in types| customFilter">type

Both are displayed in an ng-repeat and according to the selected item the other list adjusts.
eg: 1 is selected, the `state` becomes

> $scope.type=['**odd**','**prime**','square','even'];
>   $scope.items=['**1**','4','3','8'];

Elements from `array` items related to type moves to the top.

Similarly, eg: even is selected , the `state` becomes

> $scope.type=['square','**even**','odd','prime'];
>   $scope.items=['**4**','**8**','1','3'];

Bold elements are highlighted on page. I use a custom `filter` in `ng-repeat` for showing and sorting according to the relation.

What I want is after it's sorted, the same `state` is stored in the original arrays. Now when I select an element from `$scope.items` the `$scope.types` returns to the original `state` and accordingly the list on page re-adjusts which looks bad.

Comment: This is a little confusing. when you use a filter in angular the original list is not changed. Also you can use a filter in your controller to get the result of the filter and store it in another variable. is this something you need? if you want i can provide and example, but first i need to understand exacly what is your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Track the changes to the collections either by ng-change or $watch and use the $filter service in controller to get the filtered values and store it in the same array.

Sample Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/eW48QL2j30ZAKnwGzs3g?p=preview

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <select ng-model='opt1' ng-options='option for option in options1' ng-change='filter(options2, opt1)'></select>
    <select ng-model='opt2' ng-options='option for option in options2 | filter:opt1'></select>
    <button ng-click='clear()'>Clear</button>
  </body>
```

var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $filter) {
  $scope.options1 = ['A','C','J'];
  $scope.options2 = ['Andrew','Chris Martin', 'Jeeva'];
  $scope.filter = function(collection, value){
    $scope.newoptions2 = $filter('filter')(collection, value);
    console.log($scope.newoptions2);
    $scope.options2 = $scope.newoptions2;
    $scope.options1 = [value];
  };
  $scope.clear = function(){
    $scope.options1 = ['A','C','J'];
    $scope.options2 = ['Andrew','Chris Martin', 'Jeeva'];
  }
});
```

Replace the 'filter' with your 'customFilter'. Let me know if these helps.

Comment: Yes,it was helpful to change my way of approach. My problem was it was an object then i changed it into array.